# delete rows of table on checking of checkboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have table containing data . In every row there is a checkbox plus a checkbox to select all checkbox at the headers.
Upon checking this checkboxes,corresponoding rows are to be deleted from database table.Plus,on chiecking the checkbox  at the header,all rows will be deleted from the database table.How can i  achieve this asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As always start with a model:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // TODO: Fetch this from a repository
    private static List<ProductViewModel> _products = new List<ProductViewModel>
    {
        new ProductViewModel { Id = 1, Name = "Product 1" },
        new ProductViewModel { Id = 2, Name = "Product 2" },
        new ProductViewModel { Id = 3, Name = "Product 3" },
        new ProductViewModel { Id = 4, Name = "Product 4" },
        new ProductViewModel { Id = 5, Name = "Product 5" },
    };

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_products);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(IEnumerable<int> productIdsToDelete)
    {
        // TODO: Perform the delete from a repository
        _products.RemoveAll(p => productIdsToDelete.Contains(p.Id));
        return RedirectToAction("index");
    }
}
```

And finally the `Index.aspx` view:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("delete", "home", FormMethod.Post)) { %>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Select</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <%= Html.EditorForModel()%>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Delete selected products" />

<% } %>
```

And the product editor template (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/ProductViewModel.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ToDD.Controllers.ProductViewModel>" %>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%: Model.Name %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="productIdsToDelete" value="<%: Model.Id %>" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I didn't understand how is the value of the checkbox determined, can you please explain? I'm pretty new to MVC and trying to figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use AJAX. On changing the checked state, I would submit a request to delete all the selected IDs and refresh the table data.

Comment: means if on checking on the checkbox , ajax call will be made and table will be refereshed then again checking other checkbox again the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery`, some other javascript library, or just hand code an AJAX request on check of checkbox. Then alter the `DOM` on success.

Using jQuery you could do something like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" id="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" id="2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" id="3" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>


$('.check').click(function() {
    var tableRow = $(this).parent().parent();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'http://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/Controller/Action/' + id,
        success: function(data) {
            $(tableRow).remove();
        }
    });
)};
```

This is very basic implementation, you could dress it  up with some animation in the removal of the row. You also need to pass data and return data with some error handling. Check out here for a [jQuery AJAX tutorial](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: this is asp.net mvc . How should i pass information to controller, which checkboxes are selected.

Comment: probably with ID, I will post an edit with option. See new URL and ID on checkbox. I would however look into a JSON web service, much lighter and easier to do. Plus it works GREAT with MVC as there is a `JSONRESULT` action type.